# Azure web app deploy failure when following quickstart

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I follow this guide

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-java?pivots=platform-linux#code-try-7

I am trying to create a website with azure. I already created the resource, now when I go to the website it tells me to go to deployment center or quick start. I do the quick start but I run into trouble.

When running

```
mvn package azure-webapp:deploy
```

I receive

```html
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building helloworld Maven Webapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ helloworld ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) @ helloworld ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ helloworld ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/maalanis/helloworld/src/test/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ helloworld ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) @ helloworld ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ helloworld ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [helloworld] in [/home/maalanis/helloworld/target/helloworld]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/home/maalanis/helloworld/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [17 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /home/maalanis/helloworld/target/helloworld.war
[INFO] WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping
[INFO]
[INFO] --- azure-webapp-maven-plugin:1.9.1:deploy (default-cli) @ helloworld ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.384 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-08-23T06:37:15+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 44M/273M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.microsoft.azure:azure-webapp-maven-plugin:1.9.1:deploy (default-cli) on project helloworld: The value of <region> is not supported, please correct it in pom.xml. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
m
```

The region is added when running
`mvn com.microsoft.azure:azure-webapp-maven-plugin:1.9.1:config`

I select 1. Applications

on region
Region : southcentralus

Thanks

Comment: did you set the config initially?

Comment: For the resource I am using? yes I did

Comment: as per the error it says region is not set

Comment: yes, it is westus. I added the region when running :
      mvn com.microsoft.azure:azure-webapp-maven-plugin:1.9.1:config

Comment: Can u share your pom.xml file please?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are using an invalid value for the region. Please run the following azure cli command to get the list of regions/locations, and pick a value from the "name" column

```
az account list-locations -o table
```

Comment: This is when I run mvn com.microsoft.azure:azure-webapp-maven-plugin:1.9.1:config
Please confirm webapp properties
AppName : hello
ResourceGroup : helloResource
Region : southcentralus
PricingTier : PremiumV2_P1v2
OS : Linux
RuntimeStack : TOMCAT 8.5-jre8
Deploy to slot : true
Slot name : hello-slot
ConfigurationSource : null